# MS Access: text box value show #Name?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a form and set the form's `RecordSource` to a query. Below is my query:

```
SELECT GeneralT.*, SalaryT.[Status]
FROM GeneralT INNER JOIN SalaryT ON GeneralT.Deposits = SalaryT.Deposits;
```

In the form I have 4 textboxes. In the first 3 textboxes I show value from `GeneralT` table and in fourth textbox I show `SalaryT.[Status]` value. But this fourth value doesn't show in the textbox rather it show `#Name?`.

If I open the query in datasheet view I can see all the value properly. I don't understand what is wrong here. Please help me to show the result properly in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying `#Name?` for a field says that field has a control source that does not match with the query linked to the form. Some things to check:

- Make sure `Status` is a selection from one of the pre-existing options in the Control Source drop down combo box. Click on the combo box to make sure.
- Double check to make sure it is a "Text Box" and not a custom
  control.
- Make sure there isn't another text box named `Status`

Comment: well, In the same textbox when I select another options from pre-existing control source dropdown I get result but only for this one I don't get any result. Point to be noted, only this field result I get from another table but other field values come from one table

Comment: I just noticed another thing, this form is a sub form of another form. So when I open the form alone, I also see the result properly. But when I open it as a subform inside another form, I get this #Name?

Comment: What I would suggest, is to create a very simple test case with a form/subform and a query with two tables and two fields (one from each table) and see if this is a weird limitation of Access. I will try this as well, but can't until tomorrow unfortunately. Other ideas can be found in this [discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/name-error-appears-even-though-all-names-are/88720a63-09ac-4e62-9439-b51c7ffad358). Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaning the control source to just `Status` instead of `SalaryT.[Status]`. If the field name does not conflict with the naming of a field in `GeneralT`, the selected `SalaryT.[Status]` will actually be displayed named `Status`.